# How to fix this python script?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having issues with this python script, it doesn't print on a new line. I hanged some things around but i had the same problem

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time,os

os.system("clear")
time.sleep(2)

wordlist = raw_input("Path to wordlist: ")
os.system("clear")

print "Hacking in Mo's lunch number"
time.sleep(2)

passwords = open(wordlist).read().splitlines()
for password in passwords:
    os.system("clear")
    print password
    os.system("clear")
    print "Access Denied"

    if password == " 05251":
        break
        os.system("clear")
        print "Access Granted"
        time.sleep(2)
        print "Lunch number: " + password
```

I got the script working but the if statment is not woking

Comment: Don't you mean `passwords = open(...` and then for password in passwords?  Plurals can be hard. (alternative, `print passwords` instead since you mixed up `password` and `passwords`.

Comment: What is this application?  It appears that you're trying to hack someone's meal account?

Comment: You might want to look into how break statements are used.  
https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#break

Comment: it's just a simple if statement with passwordlist that i made up

Comment: isn't a hack, it's just a script that does a for loop and if statement with a previded number

Comment: What do you mean by "if statment is not woking"? It's working of course, it is just not doing what you want it to be doing. So, what is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You put the `break line` at the first position of your `if statement`, so the next lines will never be read.
Just pass your break line to the end of the if statement.

```
if password == " 05251":
    os.system("clear")
    print "Access Granted"
    time.sleep(2)
    print "Lunch number: " + password
    break
```